# Is it possible to subplot confusion matrices?

Tags: matlab, plot, machine-learning, deep-learning, matlab-figure

I'm plotting several confusion matrices using `plot_confusion()` function and I want to put them in a subplot (2x5 figures), but it does not seem to work.It displays every confusion matrix separately. Are there any restriction for plotting confusion? Thanks!

```
figure

Subplot(2,1,1);

plotconfusion(targets,outputs,'train');

subplot(2,1,2);

plotconfusion(targets1,outputs1,'test')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're "not supposed" to do that (the functionality is not included), but you can trick Matlab a little, because at the end of a day it's just an axes object:

```
%% First Example Data
[x,t] = cancer_dataset;
net = patternnet(10);
net = train(net,x,t);
y = net(x);

%// plot
plotconfusion(t,y)

%// get handle and enable second plöt
cp1 = gcf;
cp1.NextPlot = 'new'
ax1 = findobj(cp1,'Type','Axes')

%% Second Example Data
[x,t] = cancer_dataset;
net = patternnet(5);
net = train(net,2*x,t);
y = net(x);

%// plot
plotconfusion(t,y)

%// get handle and enable third plöt
cp2 = gcf;
cp2.NextPlot = 'new'
ax2 = findobj(cp2,'Type','Axes')

%% combine plots

f1 = figure(42)
f1s1 = subplot(121)
copyobj(allchild(ax1),f1s1)
f1s2 = subplot(122)
copyobj(allchild(ax2),f1s2)
```

[image]

You loose the labels and titles and may need to adjust the axis, but I guess you're able to do that.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you  "not supposed to do that"?

Comment: @AnderBiguri It was more metaphorical, as the toolbox takes care that you have absolutely no control about handles. By default it doesn't even allow you to open multiple figure windows. It is not supposed to be a normal figure or axes object you can further use for e.g. subplots.

Comment: @thewaywalk.Thank you so much for your valiant effort.As in the above confusion matrix grey boxes shows the percentages of Precision and recall.So can we plot a figure for Precision Vs Recall for each class?